# Why doesn't this parallel for loop give me speedup?

Tags: openmp

```
  int main()
{
  for (int i = 1; i < 24; i++){
    float total_time = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      omp_set_num_threads(i);
      vector<int> A(100000000,2);
      double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
        A[i] *= 2;
      }
      double time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
      total_time += time;
    }
    total_time /= 5;
    std::cout << "Number of threads: " << i << " Time(ms): " << total_time * 1000 << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The above code, which just doubles the entries in  a vector of integers, has been parallelized by varying the number of threads. On my  four-core machine, I observe no speedup. Given the simple nature of this loop, I expect to see at least some speedup. What's the issue here? How can I change it to get speedup?

Comment: Cannot replicate, the code reports speedup even in Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FBVWrpl1SOFsk2VO. What are your compiler flags?

Comment: g++ -O2 -fopenmp

Comment: Please describe your system (which CPU, what memory) and show the actual measurement results. Also try with `-O3` first.

Comment: You are reading+writing 800 MB. This is much larger than the last level cache so your code is memory bandwidth bound so you can't expect a big improvement.

Comment: Replacing simd vectorization (automatic at -O3) by omp parallel is no benefit unless (in a memory bandwidth bound case) you have multiple memory controllers.  g++ doesn't combine simd and parallel in a single loop.

Comment: @tim18 *"g++ doesn't combine simd and parallel in a single loop."* That is just not true. Take a look at https://godbolt.org/g/euD2Jc - the inner loop code uses the same SIMD instructions with or without OpenMP. You keep repeating this and I believe this to be harmful. If you are still convinced, please back it up with evidence. (I am not saying that every compiler compiles every parallel loop as efficiently as it's serial counterpart.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question lacks specific measurement results and system specification which are necessary to discuss performance.